# Can the value of partial AUC be bigger than the complete AUC?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I have two ROC curves on one plot with their corresponding AUCs. When I calculated the partial AUC, the values is bigger than the actual AUC for one of the curves. Is that possible? I am using sklean for computing partial AUC by setting max_fpr to 0.1.
How does this partial AUC is calculated?

```
from sklearn.metrics import auc, roc_auc_score
complete_AUC = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred)
partial_AUC = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred, max_fpr=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: While this question is borderline off-topic, the answer turns out to be a specific choice by `sklearn` and so I think it fits here.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because the partial AUC is not just the area shown in the figure.
From the docs (my emphasis):

> If not `None`, the **standardized** partial AUC [2] over the range [0, max_fpr] is returned. [...]

and the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L358-L362):

```py
    # McClish correction: standardize result to be 0.5 if non-discriminant
    # and 1 if maximal
    min_area = 0.5 * max_fpr**2
    max_area = max_fpr
    return 0.5 * (1 + (partial_auc - min_area) / (max_area - min_area))
```